# How can I read files outside src?

Tags: reactjs

I understand that in react you cannot `import` files outside `src` folder.
But what is the reason for it exactly and can I disable it?

In my project react web app is only part of the whole thing, and different parts share some files (configs, build output), so folder structure looks like this

```
ProjectRoot/
    config
    build-output/
    Part1/
    Part2/
    WebApp/
        src/
...
```

Sure, you can copy files or create symlinks, but that's duplication and inconvenient.

Comment: That depends on how you configure it in your webpack

Comment: React does nothing to prevent you from importing files at all. You absolutely _can_ import from outside the `src` folder. Can you share the code that is trying to do that but not working?

Comment: If you are using webpack, you can use module resolution: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules

Comment: You're using create react app tool I'm assuming... this is an issue with their preset webpack config, not a restriction of the framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a restriction of [Create React App](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html) *only*.

This tool exists to get new users up and running with the react framework as fast as possible by abstracting away the tooling.  The part of tooling that is limiting you in this instance is their **webpack configuration**, which is preset to only look for javascript files in your src directory.

That explains the *why?* but to answer the other half of your question:

> how can I disable it?

Is that you would need to [eject](https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#config-file) from Create React App and then modify your [webpack config](https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/#config-file) to allow it to search directories other than `src/`

Comment: The links for eject and webpack config are not working

Answer (score 1):

First - this has nothing to do with react itself.

If you refer to [importing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) javascript modules ([for now](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/) using module loaders like systemjs, require, etc.) then the answer is:

It depends what directory is being served by web server. If you have set up your web server to serve `WebApp/src` folder only - then no, browser will not be able to get access to the files outside and so module loaders. If you will serve all `ProjectRoot` directory - then yes, you can.

If you prepare your web application for deployment using some sort of bundlers ([webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack), [browserify](http://browserify.org/)) - it depends on how you will configure them and instruct to include the required files in the resulting bundle.